# Calling function from another process on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, process

I have two Windows applications (EXEs). I would like to do this:

A:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    MessageBox(a);
}
```

B:

```
p = CreateProcess("A.exe");
CallFunction(p, "foo", 15);
```

How this "CallFunction" can be done?

Comment: So you want Process B to be able to call a function in Process A? Are you familiar with `CreateRemoteThread`? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Gabe, there's no reason to use CreateRemoteThread if you control both processes.

Comment: @bdonlan: Yes, that would only be necessary if the OP can't listen for the RPC any other way.

Comment: You might want to give more information about what your higher-level goal is here. As bdonlan points out in the answer, there's several ways of doing something like this on windows; but which is the 'best' one may depend on what you're trying to do on the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use an IPC (Inter-Process Communication) method. There are a number of options for this, including [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model), [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [Windows messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, using Windows messages was a solid solution.